# jQuery animate not working in chrome/safari/ie

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, safari, margin, jquery-animate

I have written a few lines of jQuery to animate a div to the left/right depending on mouse movements

```
 $(".galleryNav").mousemove(function(e){
  $("#status").html(e.pageX +', '+e.pageY);

  if(e.pageX > 1100 && e.pageX < 1170){
   $(".galleryNav").animate({marginLeft:"-60px"},{queue: false, duration: 450});
  }

  if(e.pageX > 410 && e.pageX < 465){
   $(".galleryNav").animate({marginLeft:"10px"},{queue: false, duration: 450});
  }
 });
```

it works fine in firefox, but nothing happens in chrome, safari or IE.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which version of jQuery do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it works fine withe jQuery 1.4.2 + UI 8.
Check you CSS.

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly this problem...the `div` that I was animating had `position:absolute`. What fixed it for me was setting the `top` and `left` in the css. Once I added them bingo it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Works fine in chrome http://jsfiddle.net/x9eZY/ maybe the problem is elsewhere? have you encapsulated your script in `$(function(){})` like so:

```
$(function(){
    $(".galleryNav").mousemove(function(e){
      $("#status").html(e.pageX +', '+e.pageY);

      if(e.pageX > 1100 && e.pageX < 1170){
       $(".galleryNav").animate({marginLeft:"-60px"},{queue: false, duration: 450});
      }

      if(e.pageX > 410 && e.pageX < 465){
       $(".galleryNav").animate({marginLeft:"10px"},{queue: false, duration: 450});
      }
    });
})  
​
```